# Reveal standalone module not working as expected

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

I've been using the Reveal module for over a year now using the original version from the Zurb Playground Site (http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin), but I've been having some issue with it so decided to try run just using the Foundation version. I found out I can download just the plugin, so I did that, but when I try use it nothing happens. :/

I followed the documentation at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

I did modify some of the CSS, but that shouldn't make any difference.

How can I get this running?

I tried posting this to the Foundation Forum but the Publish button wasn't working

### Edit

I've just found when debugging the following error shows up:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-'Times New Roman'-reveal] jquery.js:1924
at.error jquery.js:1924
bt jquery.js:2527
At jquery.js:2914
at jquery.js:1283
at.matches jquery.js:1862
x.extend.filter jquery.js:5945
ft jquery.js:5995
x.fn.extend.is jquery.js:5783
a foundation.min.js:8
Foundation.libs.reveal.init foundation.reveal.js:40
t.Foundation.init_lib foundation.min.js:8
t.Foundation.init foundation.min.js:8
(anonymous function) foundation.min.js:8
x.extend.each jquery.js:657
x.fn.x.each jquery.js:266
e.fn.foundation foundation.min.js:8
(anonymous function) (index):23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2112-foundation-5100-syntax-error-in-js

```
$(function(){
    Foundation.global.namespace = '';
    $(docment).foundation();
});
```

Comment: My god. Thank you. Spent two days trying to figure out an issue that ended up being caused by this in my rails app while using Jasmine testing.